# How to count total number of patients in a certain age group

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: table picture]

Hello I would like to ask how can I have the total number of patients in certain distinct age groups using queries?

Comment: Don't post data sample as image but text. Or even better, create a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Comment: mysql sorry im new here thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL. In other DBMS similarly, but you must precise what you use.

```
SELECT AgeGroup, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY AgeGroup ORDER BY AgeGroup.
```